# How to redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am having a following htaccess rule to redirect all the subdomain requests to my web page index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?subdomain=%1
```

Now I want to redirect some of the subdomain requests to someother webpage category.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^jobs\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)/subfolder$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^jobs\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)/subfolder/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ category.php?did=%1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?subdomain=%1
```

But the code is not redirected to category.php instead it redirects to index.php

Please help me solve this problem

Edited code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^jobs\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)/subfolder$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^jobs\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)/subfolder/$
RewriteRule ^jobs\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)/subfolder$   category.php?did=jobs [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^jobs\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)/subfolder/$   category.php?did=jobs [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !category.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?subdomain=%1
```

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` certainly does _not_ contain a path as you appear to expect... It contains the requested host name. Not more, not less.

Comment: Plus, even if you did suscessfully rewrite the request to category.php internally - on the next round _that_ would be rewritten to index.php again (because `^.*$` matches `category.php`)

Comment: @CBroe is there a solution for this? please help me I am new to this

Comment: You’ll need another check to do the last rewrite only if the internal URL path is not `category.php` already.

Comment: @CBroe could you please post it as an answer. please...  I have added L here in this line RewriteRule ^.*$ category.php?did=%1 [L,QSA] to stop processing.. doesn't it work?

Comment: No, it doesn’t work that way. The L/Last flag only affects the current “iteration” of evaluating the rules. But when you configure rewriting in .htaccess context, it loops - the internally re-written URL is fed into this process again, and all the conditions and rules are applied again on this “new” URL. This process only stops if after no more rewrites occur.

Comment: @CBroe I haved edited the code but still it's not working

Comment: Well for starters, you have still ignored what @arkascha said in the very first comment.